# mkdir variable Dont work

Tags: mkdir

I need to create a script for school but it doesn't seem to work,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hoeveel vakken heb jij deze periode?"
read $AANTAL


if [ -d "/home/school/jaar_1/periode_4" ];

then
    echo "directoy bestaat al."

else

    mkdir -p /home/school/jaar_1/periode_4/vak{1..$AANTAL}


fi
```

Comment: Which error message are you getting? Maybe you need a "for" loop to make each "vak{X}" subdir. Also, I believe you shouldn't have $ in front of variable when reading the value.

Comment: $AANTAL is a varaible but he makes it as a name 'vak{1..$AANTAL}

Comment: i need this, vak1, vak 2, vak 3,

Comment: Yes I figured that. Try this: 
for i in {1..$AANTAL}; do
    mkdir -p /home/school/jaar_1/periode_4/$i
done (linebreaks before mkdir and done)

Comment: Hey perhaps I can help you. Answer some questions. What is the error you're getting?
What do you want to do? (what is the program exactly aimed to achieve?) I have some suggestions. 1. Try running script with sudo su.

Comment: @Prakhar I'm pretty sure that running the script using `sudo su` has no effect here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. When debugging remember you can type these commands individually and add echo commands to debug by outputting the values of the variables at each stage. Note that your read command was also incorrectly referring to $AANTAL instead of AANTAL.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hoeveel vakken heb jij deze periode?"
read AANTAL

if [ -d "/home/school/jaar_1/periode_4" ];

then
     echo "directoy bestaat al."

else
     for i in $(seq 1 $AANTAL)
          do
          mkdir -p /home/school/jaar_1/periode_4/vak$i
          done
fi
```

Comment: thanks i think it works after i solved the problem for ' unexpected file ending '

Comment: As you are a new user, I thought i should advise that the typical response is to upvote this answer and mark "accepted answer" if it works for you, to stop a proliferation of other suggestions.

Comment: Would you mind adding the closing `fi` so that your code is complete? Also, `$( ... )` is nowadays preferred over backticks for command substitution.

Comment: Thanks, applied the edits as requested.